# Wait for ADC interrupts with Embedded Rust and Embassy on STM32 microcontroller

Tags: asynchronous, rust, embedded, stm32

Using embedded Rust and embassy, I'm trying to wait for an async event from the ADC peripheral. The event I try to wait is the "end of conversion" event, generated by the peripheral as an interrupt.

I configured the peripheral thanks to this example: https://github.com/embassy-rs/embassy/blob/master/examples/stm32f4/src/bin/adc.rs but there is no explanation on how to use interrupts with this.

I checked for documentation but couldn'd find any information on how to wait on custom async events. The only thing I could find is interrupting on IO ports.

I found the `interrupts::ADC` struct in the embassy_stm32 crate but couldn't find any other information on how to use... There seems to be no function looking like `wait_for_irq`, nor any function I could use to create the struct (as for `ExtiInput::new`)

Is there any documentation on how to use peripheral interrupts ? I read the the official documentation (https://embassy.dev/dev/runtime.html):

> There exists a special executor named InterruptExecutor which can be driven by an interrupt. This can be used to drive tasks at different priority levels by creating multiple InterruptExecutor instances.

but I can't find anything else about that...

Any intel is very appreciated ! I like the idea for async for embedded software but documentation is (for now) very scarce.

My setup:

- stm32f446re Nucleo development board
- embassay_stm32 0.1.0